# Re-render of h:form using a4j:commandLink or a4j:commandButton does not work in IE9

Tags: ajax, jsf, internet-explorer-9, render

I have h:form with some content and few links and buttons. a4j:commandLink/Button with render="@form" is used inside the form but when I click on this link ajax error comes up with XML response body. This issue is only coming in IE9.

It works perfectly in Firefox, chrome, IE7, IE8. Also, when I rerender section of form instead of complete form, it works fine.

Does anybody have clue about this, please?

Comment: any chance you got nested forms ? form inside another form ? also do you see any errors in the dev tools of IE9 ? (F12 -> console)

Comment: No, I have only single form. No error on dev tools too. Its only after I added below lines, I am able to view this error.
 <script>   
 function handleAjaxError(data) {
 alert("Message: " + data.errorMessage + 
 " RequestStatus: " + data.status + "     RequestStatusResponseText: " + data.responseText);
    alert(data.description);
    alert(data.errorName);
    alert(data.source);
    return null;
   }
    
   if (typeof jsf !== 'undefined') {
       jsf.ajax.addOnError(handleAjaxError);
   }  
  </script>

Comment: RequestStatus is coming as "clientError". Rest all are coming as undefined. In RequestStatusResponseText, I am getting response XML which seems to be correct.

Comment: take a close look at all your third party included jquery libs... maybe some conflicts/load order/multiple includes/jquery itself being included several time/<!--[if lte IE 9]> etc...

Comment: No luck :(. Just to mention that issue comes up only when I rerender entire form. It works fine when I just rerender section of it.

Comment: Strange behavior of browser. When debugger/dev tools (F12) window is on, ajax error do not come (Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode: IE9 Standards). Not sure whats causing this, may be the change in document mode is happening somehow.

Comment: You can start removing elements from that form to pin point which one is the problematic one

Comment: Thanks Daniel for all your suggestions. Much appreciated. I have added answer to this now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of debugging, found that I was including some jquery JS files in inner XHTML which was included in dynamically. That inner XHTML has commandLink/commandButton which fire re-render of form. IE9 doesn't like this.

I moved js file inclusion `script` tag to Outer XHTML outside of h:form which resolved the issue.